# Matlab, is there any way to manipulate random variable

Tags: statistics, matlab, probability-density

In Maple, there is some feature that allows you to calculate the pdf of a function of a random variable. For example, if X is exponentially distributed, and you want to know the distribution of X^2, then there is a function that will do that for you.

**My question is , is there a functionality in matlab that allows you to do so? I have looked through the matlab's guide, but I didn't see it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Statistics toolbox includes many [probability distributions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/supported-distributions.html) for you to choose from, both parametric and non-parametric distributions. For each it provides functions for PDF, CDF, fitting, random number generation, etc..

I suggest you start with the "Distribution Fitting app": `dfittool`.

---

### EDIT:

In addition, MuPAD has support for a number of [distributions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/probability-density-functions.html), which you can manipulate symbolically. Example:

[image: mupad_symbolic_math_toolbox]

The function [`intlib::changevar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/intlib-changevar.html) might be of interest here, though it seems intended for integrals...

Comment: The problem as OP stated it doesn't have anything to do with fitting distributions to data.

Comment: @RobertDodier: sorry I've never used Maple myself.. Can you refer me to the function the OP is talking about? (a link to online documentation would be best). Perhaps I can point them to the equivalent in MATLAB (if there is one).. The reason I mentioned distribution fitting is because I think that's one way to do it (obtain a sufficiently large random samples from X, compute X^2, empirically fit a distribution on that)

Comment: Matlab has a Symbolic Math Toolbox. I don't know if the toolbox has a specific function for the function-of-a-random-variable problem stated by OP, but one could solve it using equation solving and integration functions.

Comment: @RobertDodier: ok I've added an example of symbolic manipulation of PDF functions. (MuPAD is the engine that powers the Symbolic Math Toolbox, in the past it used to be Maple)

Comment: Thanks for info about MuPAD. Note that the distribution of X^2 where X has some PDF, say f, is not `f(x)^2`, but rather a more complicated formula. The general technique is called the "change of variables" formula; a web search yields many results. For example, see "Dependent variables and change of variables" at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: @RobertDodier: oops, sorry I got a bit confused there with the X^2 :) I guess my intention was to show that it's capable of manipulating symbolic expressions.. Now I see that one has to apply the ["change-of-variable"](http://www.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring11/sta114/lec/114mvnorm.pdf) technique to get the PDF of X^2. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're interested in getting the values of the PMF, or discrete PDF, then, given `x` some RV with some distribution,

```
my_pmf = hist(x)/sum(x);
```

So try,

```
doc hist
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wanted. He/she wants methods to manipulate random variables, not find PDFs.

Comment: Wow, feisty. I did not understand that from the question.  Also, Matlab is numerical not exact. If, due to round off it sums bit exact to one that's on the developer to be aware of. I offered the standard text book derivation of PMF.

Comment: Not being feisty. Just pointing out that this is probably not they want.  Apologies if you interpreted differently.